# Can't install RCurl from source: dylib libomp.dynlib was built for a newer MacOS Version

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I'm trying to install RCurl from source after making sure the path to curl is using the homebrew version that has sftp protocol, as the default MacOS (12.3.1) does not include that protocol:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/curl/7.83.1/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

I get two ld warnings and then a fatal error. The first seems to be with the version of libomp.dynlib, which then leads to a second where it ignores the homebrew curl lib, then the fatal error where it fails to load Rcurl.

```
myUTF8.c:58:34: warning: variable 'use_wcs' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   Rboolean oct_or_hex = FALSE, use_wcs = FALSE;
                                ^
myUTF8.c:58:14: warning: variable 'oct_or_hex' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   Rboolean oct_or_hex = FALSE, use_wcs = FALSE;
            ^
2 warnings generated.
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lomp -o RCurl.so base64.o curl.o curlInit.o curl_base64.o enums.o json.o memoryManagement.o myUTF8.o -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/curl/7.83.1/lib -lcurl -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -licucore -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (12.0) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/curl/7.83.1/lib/libcurl.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-RCurl/00new/RCurl/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RCurl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-RCurl/00new/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-RCurl/00new/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_curl_easy_cleanup'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/RCurl’
```

```
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
 os       macOS Monterey 12.3.1
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0
 ui       AQUA
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8
 tz       America/Denver
 date     2022-06-21
 pandoc   NA
```

Here is the entire output of the installation from source attempt (sorry had to use image, as I was out of characters):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems the problem is not in RCurl itself but in the version of curl you installed (with Homebrew?) You have macOS 12.x and the Homebrew version is for 10.13, and also it seems you installed the M1 version while you have an Intel processor. Could you try this: https://blog.arturofm.com/solve-warning-was-built-for-newer-macos-version-xcode/ to see if at least the ld warning about dylib disappears? And update + upgrade Homebrew to see if you have the latest curl.

Comment: @CasparV. I have the latest homebrew version of curl (7.83.1), and I am on an M1 processor.  I tried resetting the xcode path using the arturoforum link you shared, but it also did not have any effect.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error and can't help any further. I'd advice to check if your curl really works before trying to install RCurl.